ASB Queue using MassTransit - How to achieve higher concurrency with lesser prefetch count
We are using Azure Service Bus queue (using Mass Transit) and multiple runners listening to the queue to process the messages from Queue. To avoid over provisioning infra, We have limited the runners to a fixed number, and most of the tasks would take few minutes to complete and a single runner need to process multiple tasks concurrently to achieve desired performance. So we have set PrefetchCount=6 based on some load testing.
The problem is, when the queue has memory intensive heavy tasks, I expect the tasks to be distributed evenly to all runners. but because of Prefetch=6, 6 heavy tasks going to the same runner even though other runners are idle. Causing Out of memory error on the runner.
Is there any way to achieve lesser prefetch (so that heavy tasks did not end up same runner) and higher concurrency?
I assumed, Reducing the prefetchcount to 1 would help to fetch 1 message each time, and keeping concurrencyMessageLimit to higher value would help achieve concurrency, but it did not worked. When prefetch reduced to 1, runner is not processing the second message until first message processing completed. By definitions of mass transit (Attached), this looks expected.

PrefetchCount does not influence concurrency. It controls how many messages are queued on the client side to minimize the wait time for the client to get notifications for processing and improve the overall throughput. It's an Azure Service Bus SDK client setting you control via the MassTransit API.
MassTransit controls consumer processing concurrency through ConcurrentMessageLimit, specified via the receiving endpoint settings.
But there's a relationship between the two settings you have to keep in mind. If your concurrency is high and fetch supplies enough messages to keep the endpoint busy, you are maximizing your hardware utilization. And if processing is memory-heavy, you might run out of memory, as you've observed. Lowering concurrency will help. But you need to adjust the prefetch so that you don't over-fetch, causing pre-fetched messages to become stale and lose their lock tokens. Unfortunately, today, this would cause the LockLostException.
TL;DR: concurrency and prefetch go hand-in-hand, but concurrency is set on the MassTransit API. Identify the concurrency your hardware allows and adjust prefetch accordingly.
You could have PrefetchCount set to hundreds of messages, but ConcurrentMessageLimit is limited to a few dozen.
